# Woocommerce - Override shipping fee based on Product Add-on

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a store that sells gift cards. They are a variable product in denominations of £25. Shipping is either a flat rate called 'Royal Mail' which costs £2.75 or local pickup called 'Collection'.

A customer can add a presentation gift box when buying a gift card. I've created it using Woocommerce Product Add-ons. It's a checkbox with a price. As it's bigger item, the shipping cost needs to be £6 (not £2.75)

I need to override the shipping fee if the presentation gift box is checked.

This is my original code for overriding the shipping fee:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates' );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates ) {
    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $rates[$key]->cost = 6;
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

I can't work out how to make the shipping price conditional upon the checkbox. It should be £2.75 for 'Royal Mail' unless the checkbox is marked, in which case it should be £6 for 'Royal Mail' (or free if they choose local pickup).

Can anybody help with making the shipping conditional upon the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a loop within the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter to check each item in the customer's cart and then look for whether the gift box add-on has been selected for any item. That involves checking the add-on data attached to each cart item and If the gift box add-on is detected, update the shipping cost for `'Royal Mail'` to `£6`. If the add-on is not in the cart, retain the default shipping cost of £2.75

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates' );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates ) {
    $gift_box_added = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['addons'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $cart_item['addons'] as $addon ) {
                if ( $addon['name'] == 'Presentation Gift Box' && $addon['value'] != '' ) {
                    $gift_box_added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( $gift_box_added ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) {
        if ( 'Royal Mail' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $rates[$key]->cost = $gift_box_added ? 6 : 2.75;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: I've tested this just now and I'm sorry to say it doesn't work. Everything looks right with the code but something stops it overriding the shipping cost.